# PHPUnit throws "Warning: date(): It is not safe..."

Tags: phpunit, warnings

When running `phpunit --coverage-html` I get the well-known warning about *timezones*.

> PHP Warning:  date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone
>   settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the
>   date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those
>   methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely
>   misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for
>   now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone.

Everything works as expected, but it becomes really annoying.

Of course, I could solve this by changing my `php.ini`, but I'd prefer to avoid it, if possible, in order to keep some *server-agnosticism*. In addition, I don't want to prevent this warning to appear if triggered by my testable code.

Is there a way to define the default timezone only for internal PHPUnit operations?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I set the TimeZone in the bootstrap.php file.

```
<?php
// PHP and Web server settings
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
date_default_timezone_set("America/Toronto");       // Set the default timezone
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] = 'http://myserver';       // Set Web Server name

// Process the Include Path to allow the additional application to be set.
$IncludePaths = explode( PATH_SEPARATOR, get_include_path() );
$NewIncludePaths = array_merge( $IncludePaths, array(dirname(__FILE__) ));
set_include_path( implode( PATH_SEPARATOR, array_unique($NewIncludePaths)));    // Update Include Path

//define('PHPUNIT_RUNNING', 1); // Indicate to the code that Automated Testing is running.
?>
```

Comment: But this way, if there's an *unsafe* `date()` within my code, will it throw an alert?

Comment: @simbirsk I do not believe it will, as the TimeZone is now set in PHP.  This setting is the same as having set the time zone in the INI file.

Comment: That's exactly the problem, I don't want to mask any warning thrown by my code, if possible.

Comment: @simbirsk Production code will send the warning, your test code will not.  Production code should not through this warning though, since you do not want end users seeing it.  Likely better to handle it and send an internal email or something for the problem.  When testing though, the warning is not an issue, and you could test that the proper time zone is set, or a wrong one to ensure your bootstrap.php is working properly.